# char pointer not returning proper value

Tags: c, pointers, character

In below code ptr prints "hello world" but temp is blank though I am passing temp as address.What can be possible reasons?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h
unsigned char temp[1024];

void func(unsigned char *ptr)
{
  const char* x = "hello world";

  ptr = (unsigned char*) x;

  printf("ptr=%s\n",ptr);
}

int main ()
{


  func(temp);
  printf("temp=%s\n",temp);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the *shadow parameter passing* used in C.

On the inside of `func`, you are changing a local *shadow* of temp and making it point to "hello world" interned string. This does not change the original pointer temp in `main` context.

In order to change `temp` you must pass a pointer to `temp` in and adjust it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(unsigned char **ptr)
{
  const char *x = "hello world";
  *ptr = (unsigned char*) x;
}

int main ()
{
  unsigned char *temp;
  func(&temp);
  printf("temp=%s\n",temp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The term _shadow parameter passing_ is unusual terminology — certainly not the standard terminology. But the basic diagnosis is correct: you pass the pointer by value, and change the local copy of the pointer in the function without changing the pointer in the calling code. If you want to change a pointer in a function, you have to pass the address of the pointer to be changed to the function, just as if you want to change an `int` passed to a function, you have to pass the address of the `int` to be changed to the function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yep; the parameter is passed as a shadow (or copy). 
i think the usual terminology might be by-value, which is a bit misleading, as it copies the value and doesnt change it..